# JSF Primefaces not rendering components

Tags: jsf, primefaces

For some reason my Primefaces is not rendering, i'm running with Eclipse and Tomcat.

As you can see on the image bellow, this is a test table with some fake data, and its not showing properly the table.
If i change the `<p:dataTable>` to `<h:dataTable>` it works properly.
As you can see too, there is an commandButton on the top without the primefaces theme for some reason.

Thank you guys!

[Datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NCVb.png)

my ExpensesList.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:mp="http://primefaces.org/ui/material">

<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    <p:commandButton value="teste" />   
    <p:dataTable id="expenses" value="#{expensesController.dao.listAll()}" var="obj"
        frame="box" rules="all" cellpadding="8">

        <p:column headerText="Date">
            <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.date}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="costCenter">
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.costCenter}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Description">
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.description}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Diaria">
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.diaria}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="KM">
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.km}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

My Web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>rd</display-name>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
  <param-value>enable</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>vader</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: from this i can only advise you to check on your pom.xml to see if theres anything wrong or if you dont use maven, just insert the newest version of primefaces again and check if the declaration for the p namespace has no typeos

Comment: Hello Azazel, thank you for your answer. I tried copying the pom.xml file from my last project that was fine and still not working.

Comment: try **rightclick on maven project** in eclipse and select **update project**, sometimes that helps, and please check if you have   **xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"** exactly like that

Comment: If i set **xmlns:p="primefaces.org/ui";** i got this message: **Warning: This page calls for XML namespace primefaces.org/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.**. with `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` no problem occurs but still not rendering properly

Comment: update your project, select everything but offline in the checkboxes menu that will appear, it will try updating and refreshing your dependencies. after that, reopen eclipse and see if it works..

did it work before in this project?

Comment: Yes, and did again after you asked and still not working =(

Comment: idk, try a reboot, it wont hurt xD but we need some more information/code to make other guesses what could be wrong

Comment: Added some code on the initial description, thank you!

Comment: if you get this error, the PrimeFaces jar is **not** in your deployed project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial Mistake.

Added the `<h:head></h:head>` on the xhtml and on the pom.xml file added the all-themes for prime faces:

```
<repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
</repository>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```